# how to get speedy loading website on android devices

Tags: android

My site https://usedfurniture-uae.com/ working fine on PC/Laptop based browser but not on android devices. Loading and viewing is too slow. Can anyone help please.

Comment: What have you tested or considered so far? So people don't waste time re-doing what you have done already.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.